# Ugly URL to pretty URL

Tags: .htaccess

I have this URL

`www.example.com/index.php?key1=val1&key2=val2&key3=val3` and so on

and I want after sending my request, I see something like this in URL bar:

`example.com/key1/val1/key2/val2/key3/val3` and so on.

I want to be able to use both kind of URL and always see something like the second url in URL bar.

Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible ... the magic thing is called MOD_REWRITE for Apache-Servers. Just goolge or search here for more infos

Comment: @donald123 Is it possible for you to give me code example, I know little bit of MOD_REWRITE but I'm not a pro.

Comment: @donald123 I can redirect the second URL to first one but I don't know how to do it vice versa.

Comment: post what you have tried please

Comment: I have have cms that only works if htaccess works, and I want it to be able to work even without htaccess. I have different approach right now and I want to change it to what I ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)(.*)$ /$3?$1=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This will change all path nodes into key/value parameters, as long as any of the keys aren't files or directories in your document root.

Comment: I can not test your code at the moment. does your code work for any number of variable?

Comment: @Eeliya Yes, because it relies on the rewrite engine to loop, so it will continually match 2 path nodes, change them into a key/value pair in the query string, then loop until there's nothing left.